# PBI REST API Get Group Users error message, "One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod"

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am executing the "Get Group Users" Powerbi API using Powershell cmd "Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod". There is an error, but the message is very general and says, "One or more errors occurred". Can anyone help with error? I am an admin for the workspace.

Link: [PBI REST API - Get Group Users | MSFT Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/get-group-users#permissions)

---

Powershell:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -environment USGOV

# HCDW Payroll | Workspace
# 5de1d95d-8248-4dbf-b051-02ef59e36e74

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url https://api.powerbigov.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/5de1d95d-8248-4dbf-b051-02ef59e36e74/users -Method GET
```

Error:

```
<#
... API Call ...
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or more errors occurred.
At line:21 char:16
+     $resultJson = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $pbiURL -Method GET
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod

Edited<https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:5f4ab07ae24e44e7bc72d635fbdbcac3@thread.tacv2/1697206568750?tenantId=e95f1b23-abaf-45ee-821d-b7ab251ab3bf&amp;groupId=d5ef4b59-25f1-4ff6-95ad-685c400765b8&amp;parentMessageId=1697206568750&amp;teamName=Power BI Community (D&amp;A/OIT)&amp;channelName=General Power BI Questions&amp;createdTime=1697206568750&amp;allowXTenantAccess=false>
#>
```